# How to save a form which has been generated by overriding __init__?

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

I have a form -

```
class PermissionForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PermissionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        permissions = Permissions.objects.all()
        for permission in permissions:
            self.fields[permission.name] = forms.CharField()
```

Now since I don't know the field names, so how do I write the save method for this form?

Comment: Why do you need to know the names? Just iterate through `self.cleaned_data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for field in self.fields
```

Or do I miss something ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get this.

Comment: @joelgoldstick why? the form is not a model form.